# Microsoft Defender configuration script failed. Please look for "WindowsDefenderChecker" records in the log

Tags: intellij-idea

Since I've moved to the new IntelliJ IDEA (2023.1 Community Edition), every time I create/import project, I get:

[image]

When I, however, click <kbd>Automatically</kbd>, it ends up showing:

[image]

and in the logs, there's only:

```
2023-04-23 21:52:54,529 [ 250961]   INFO - #c.i.d.WindowsDefenderChecker - validation failed:
[-1] C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe [-NoProfile, -NonInteractive, -Command, (Get-AuthenticodeSignature 'C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.2\bin\defender-exclusions.ps1').Status]
```

If it matters, this happens in both scenarios - when I use classical (old) or new UI.

Comment: Try to execute the script manually using the command line. Also, you can configure Windows Defender manually as per https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560

Comment: How do you start IntelliJ IDEA? From the terminal or via the start menu?

Comment: @Postlagerkarte just from the shortcut, which refers to the .exe executable file on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Adding powershell.exe to my system path variable fixed the issue for me.

[Adding path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oogwq.png)

Answer (score 0):

The log file doesn't provide much information about the cause of the error.
I suggest you restart the IDE and look into the cause of the problem in the suggested log file that it may

In my case, I uses Android Studio (a kind of IntelliJ IDE) and when I look into the log file, the `idea.log` file says:

```
[1] C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\launcher.exe 
[C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe, - 
ExecutionPolicy, Bypass, -NoProfile, -NonInteractive, -File, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\defender-exclusions.ps1, C:\Users\Aryo\.gradle, C:\Users\Aryo\AndroidStudioProjects\BukuTelepon, C:\Users\Aryo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, C:\Users\Aryo\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2023.2]
output: skipped: C:\Users\Aryo\.gradle
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'D' does not exist.
at Test-Excluded, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\defender-exclusions.ps1: line 23
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\defender-exclusions.ps1: line 42
```

The error on the log file clearly said that:

```
Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'D' does not exist.
```

Weird enough is that, I don't have 'D' drive on my computer and all of my Android Studio project is located on 'C' drive. The one that I currently opened is also on 'C' drive.

To solve the problem, I do the followIng steps:

- Plugged a USB flash drive stick,
- Open Windows Explorer and see the USB stick drive letter.
- When it says the USB drive is other than 'D', e.g., 'E' or 'F', I run 'Disk Management', select the USB drive, and change/assign the USB drive letter to 'D'.
- Restart Android Studio, open the project (if it doesn't open the project automatically)
- Wait for a moment for the Microsoft Defender configuration notification to appear
- Click the `Automatically` link on the notification to add to the Microsoft Defender exclusion list.

In my case, it solve the problem. Hope this helps.